# What is the maximum size for an FTP welcome message?

Tags: networking, ftp, stream, network-protocols, tcp

For avoiding buffer overflow in FTP welcome message, what is the maximum size for it?

I know it could contain multiple lines, for example:

```
220-QTCP at fran.csg.stercomm.com.
220 Connection will close if idle more than 5 minutes.
```

but is there a specifications for how many rows or char is it suppose to contain?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are generally no limits specified in FTP specifications.

Quoting [RFC 624 section 5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc624#section-5):

> 5. There is no specified maximum length of a TELNET command line,
>    TELNET reply line, user name, password, account, or pathname.

It refers to *"TELNET lines"* because FTP control connection uses the TELNET protocol format. Quoting [RFC 959 section 2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959#page-3):

> control connection
>
> The communication path between the USER-PI and SERVER-PI for
> the exchange of commands and replies.  This connection follows
> the Telnet Protocol.